# constraint generic type T and K where K extends keyof T and T[K] is boolean?

Tags: typescript

I can't make following function type checked without using `any` somewhere.

```
export function makeToggleState<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: {new(): T}, prop: K) {
  return (state: T, show: boolean|null = null) => {
    if (show === null) {
      state[prop] = !state[prop]
    } else {
      state[prop] = show
    }
  }
}

class State {
    value = true
}

makeToggleState(State, 'value')
```

I am getting this error:

```
Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'T[K]'.
  Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'T[string]'.
(parameter) prop: K extends keyof T
```

What is the best way to tell compiler I want `K extends keyof T` and `T[K] is boolean`?

Comment: Will all the members of the `T` (in this case `State`) be booleans?

Comment: @NitzanTomer Not for my case. But a solution for all members are booleans is also useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to have this constraint in `makeToggleState` declaration, but you can declare it for the function it returns, using intersection of T and [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) `T & {[n in K]: boolean}` for its state parameter.

```
export function makeToggleState<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: {new(): T}, prop: K) {
    return (state: T & {[n in K]: boolean}, show: boolean|null = null) => {
    if (show === null) {
      state[prop] = !state[prop]
    } else {
      state[prop] = show
    }
  }
}

class State {
    value = true;
    name = 'q';
}

const toggleValue = makeToggleState(State, 'value');

const s = new State();
toggleValue(s)


const toggleName = makeToggleState(State, 'name'); // ok

// but does not compile when you try to use it
toggleName(s);

//Argument of type 'State' is not assignable to parameter of type 'State & { name: boolean; }'.
//  Type 'State' is not assignable to type '{ name: boolean; }'.
//    Types of property 'name' are incompatible.
//      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```